# resizing flipclock.js not resizing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://flipclockjs.com/

I'm using the default clockface, all I want to do is roughtly resize by 1/3 but for whatever reason it isn't resizing as I expect

In flipclock css I changed the following

```
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
width: 20px;
height: 30px;
font-size: 27px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 29px;
border-radius: 6px;
background: #000;
}
```

but the width of each ul is is 40px;

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great..

Comment: I believe your CSS is overridden by the default plugin CSS.. Try to look for how to use option `classes`, which in the documentation says,
`(object) This is an object of CSS classes to use to append to DOM objects`.

Comment: I'm editing the default css. When inspected it shows the change as applied, but when computed it is different

Answer (score 23):

I leave a comment for upcoming questionnaires

To fix size issue in *FlipClock*, simply add following css to your main clock container

```
.timer {
    zoom: 0.5;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

above line will reduce size by 1/2, if you want smaller size you can use 0.3 or whatever

Comment: this is not a good solution because still the margin and all other settings are existing and it destroy the page layout

Answer (score 0):

Flipclockjs is built on many fixed properties. You must adjust more than that.
An example I use with responsive method to override them:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 819px) {

    /*.home-featured .clock { margin: 0 auto; display: block; width: 322px; }*/
    .home-featured h1 { font-size: 1.6em; }

    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { height: 50px; line-height: 50px; margin: 3px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after { top: 24px; }
    .flip-clock-divider { height: 50px; }
    .flip-clock-dot { height: 6px; width: 6px; left: 7px;}
    .flip-clock-dot.top { top: 17px; }
    .flip-clock-dot.bottom { bottom: 8px; }

    .flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label { font-size: 16px; }
    .flip-clock-divider.days .flip-clock-label { right: -76px; }
    .flip-clock-divider.hours .flip-clock-label { right: -70px; }
    .flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label { right: -64px; }
    .flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label { right: -70px; }

    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { width: 37px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn { font-size: 38px; }

    /* Korekcja położenia pól zegara załamanych do nowej linii */
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { margin-bottom: 35px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper { margin-bottom: -35px; }
}

.flip-clock-divider.minutes { clear: none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {

    .flip-clock-divider.minutes { clear: left;} /* break clock at minutes */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It been some time since this was active but I've bumped into this lib and I've decided I'll give it a try. Things have been working out alright for now. This is a solution adapted from one of the repo's [closed issue](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/issues/13#issuecomment-140015124) (unsolved). It seems that the dev's promised a new API but that was more than 1 year ago.

It's not perfect as there are some issues when setting `$clock-flip-font-size: 120px`. Also, when minutes are being displayed as 3 digits, the "Minutes" text is not `centered`.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/jimasun/pen/PzAqVw/

```
// 
// ------------------------- FlipClock
// 
$clock-flip-font-size: 120px
$clock-flip-border-radius: 8px
$clock-digit-gap: 20px
$clock-dot-size: 20px

$clock-height: ($clock-flip-font-size * 1.2)
$clock-flip-width: ($clock-flip-font-size * 0.8)
$clock-flip-margin: ($clock-digit-gap / 2)
$clock-flip-section-width: (2 * ($clock-flip-width + 2 * $clock-flip-margin))

$clock-flip-bg: #607D8B
$clock-flip-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
$clock-flip-font-color: #F44336
$clock-flip-font-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000

.countdown-wrapper
  left: 50%
  position: absolute
  top: 50%
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul
  height: $clock-height
  margin: 0 $clock-flip-margin
  width: $clock-flip-width
  box-shadow: $clock-flip-shadow

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li
  line-height: $clock-height

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn
  background-color: $clock-flip-bg
  color: $clock-flip-font-color
  font-size: $clock-flip-font-size
  text-shadow: $clock-flip-font-shadow

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul,
.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn
  border-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down
  border-bottom-left-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius
  border-bottom-right-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after
  top: (($clock-height / 2) - 1px)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot.top
  top: ($clock-height / 2 - $clock-flip-font-size * 0.2 - $clock-dot-size / 2)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot.bottom
  top: ($clock-height / 2 + $clock-flip-font-size * 0.2 - $clock-dot-size / 2)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot
  height: $clock-dot-size
  left: $clock-dot-size
  width: $clock-dot-size
  background: $clock-flip-bg

.countdown .flip-clock-divider
  height: $clock-height
  width: ($clock-dot-size * 3)
  &:first-child
    width: 0

.countdown .flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label,
.countdown .flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label
  right: -1 * $clock-flip-section-width

.countdown .flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label
  color: $clock-flip-font-color
  font-size: $clock-flip-font-size / 4
  width: 2 * $clock-flip-width + 4 * $clock-flip-margin
// 
// ------------------------- FlipClock
//
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
        width: 20px;
        height: 25px;
        line-height: 25px;
        **padding-left: 20px;** //add this  to your wrapper ul  and youll be able to set the with  you can set it to zero and just adujst your width
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```css
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  ...
  width: 20px !important;
  ...
}
```