# Make FlipClock.js Responsive

Tags: javascript, css, flipclock

I have been trying to make flipclock.js fully responsive and been failing.  Has anyone accomplished this? If so how would I get this to work? Thank you for your time. I tried to convert everything to percentages but that did not work as I expected.  I am using twitter bootstrap with this plugin.

Here is my css for flipclock.js:

```
 /* Get the bourbon mixin from http://bourbon.io */
    /* Reset */
    .countdown {
      postion:relative;
      width: 39%;
}
.flip-clock-wrapper {
  margin-left: 8% !important;
  max-width: 100%;
    font: normal .75em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.flip-clock-wrapper * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc; }

.flip-clock-wrapper a:hover {
  color: #fff; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  list-style: none; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:before,
.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1; }

.flip-clock-meridium {
  background: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 !important;
  font-size: 300% !important; }

.flip-clock-meridium a { color: #313333; }

.flip-clock-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100%;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper:before,
.flip-clock-wrapper:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.flip-clock-wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}

/* Skeleton */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.7%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 1.1em;
  font-size: 7.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 7.2em;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background: #000;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li:first-child {
  z-index: 2; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 100%; /*200px*/
  -moz-perspective: 100%;
  perspective: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  cursor: default !important; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 1em;
  overflow: hidden; 
  outline: 1% solid transparent; } /*1px*/

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  top: 0; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;/*44px*/
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: .02em;/*3px*/
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1%;/*6px*/
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1%;/*6px*/
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  color: #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0 20% 3% #000; /* 0 1px 2px #000*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 9%; /* 0 1px 2px #000*/
  font-size: 1em; } /* 70px*/

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up div.inn {
  top: 0; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down div.inn {
  bottom: 0; }

/* PLAY */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before {
  z-index: 3; }

.flip-clock-wrapper .flip {   box-shadow: 0 2% 6% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); } /* 0 2px 5px     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);*/

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active {
  -webkit-animation: asd 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: asd 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  animation: asd 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  z-index: 5; }

.flip-clock-divider {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 3%; /* 20px*/
  height: 9em; } /* 100px*/

.flip-clock-divider:first-child {
  width: 0; }

.flip-clock-dot {
  display: block;
  background: #323434;
  width: 50%;/* 10px*/
  height: 1em; /* 10px*/
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 20%; } /* 5px*/

.flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  right: -7.5em; /* 86px*/
  color: black; 
  text-shadow: none; }

.flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label {
  right: -7.6em; } /* 88px*/

.flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label {
  right: -7.9em; } /* 88px*/

.flip-clock-dot.top {
  top: 2.4em; } /* 30px*/

.flip-clock-dot.bottom {
  bottom: 2.4em; } /* 30px*/

@-webkit-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  20% {
    z-index: 4; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@-moz-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  20% {
    z-index: 4; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@-o-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  20% {
    z-index: 4; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  20% {
    z-index: 4; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@-o-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: turn2 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: turn2 0.5s linear both;
  animation: turn2 0.5s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@-o-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li.flip-clock-active {
  z-index: 3; }

/* SHADOW */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, black));
  background: linear, top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  animation: show 0.5s linear both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .up .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, black));
  background: linear, top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, black 100%;
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  -moz-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both; }

/*DOWN*/
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .down .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, black), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background: linear, top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  animation: show 0.5s linear both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, black), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background: linear, top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, black 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  -moz-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  animation: hide 0.5s 0.2s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-moz-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-o-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-moz-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-o-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }
```

Comment: you work with this plugin : http://flipclockjs.com/    ?

Comment: Yes I have been trying to get the thing to be responsive.

Answer (score 21):

Try this - 
You can control the size of the flip clock (see - https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/issues/13)
by creating new class in your css (better working with sass though):

```
.your-clock{
   zoom: 0.5;
   -moz-transform: scale(0.5)
}
```

After knowing this, by working with sass you can create mixin to control the zoom and -moz-transform by the size of the screen

For example, create a mixin file in sass that contains -

```
// Responsive mixins

=screen-xs
  @media all and (max-width: 320px)
    @content

=screen-sm
  @media all and (max-width: 479px)
    @content

=screen-md
  @media all and (max-width: 768px)
    @content

=screen-lg
  @media all and (max-width: 900px)
    @content

=screen-xl
  @media all and (max-width: 1300px)
    @content
```

Now just add it to your flipclock class to control the zoom by the screen size:

```
.myflipclock
  zoom: 0.8
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8)
  +screen-md
    zoom: 0.6
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6)
  +screen-sm
    zoom: 0.45
    -moz-transform: scale(0.45)
```

etc...

Hope it helps

Comment: It helped. Thanks.

Comment: This has horrendous/unexpected results on ios Safari. ios Chrome gives different wrong results. In short-- zoom isn't ready for action across the board.

Comment: It causes unexpected problem specially when the container is resized. browser still considers the original size

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following code to the bottom of your flipclock.css file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .clock { margin: 0 auto; display: block; width: 100%; }

    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { height: 35px; line-height: 35px; margin:2px; width: 24px !important;}
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after { top: 16px; }
    .flip { width: 24px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider { height: 35px; width: 10px !important;}
    .flip-clock-dot { height: 4px; width: 4px; left: 2px !important;}
    .flip-clock-dot.top { top: 12px; }
    .flip-clock-dot.bottom { bottom: 6px; }

    .flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label { font-size: 11px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider.days .flip-clock-label { right: -42px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider.hours .flip-clock-label { right: -42px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label { right: -48px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label { right: -50px !important; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li { line-height: 35px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { width: 24px !important; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn { font-size: 21px; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .clock { margin: 0 auto; display: block; width: 100%; }

    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { height: 35px; line-height: 35px; margin:2px; width: 30px !important;}
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after { top: 16px; }
    .flip { width: 30px; }
    .flip-clock-divider { height: 35px; width: 15px;}
    .flip-clock-dot { height: 4px; width: 4px; left: 4px !important;}
    .flip-clock-dot.top { top: 12px; }
    .flip-clock-dot.bottom { bottom: 6px; }

    .flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label { font-size: 11px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider.days .flip-clock-label { right: -46px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider.hours .flip-clock-label { right: -46px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label { right: -55px !important; }
    .flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label { right: -55px !important; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li { line-height: 35px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { width: 26px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn { font-size: 21px; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .clock { margin: 0 auto; display: block; width: 100%; }

    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { height: 50px; line-height: 50px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after { top: 24px; }
    .flip-clock-divider { height: 50px; }
    .flip-clock-dot { height: 6px; width: 6px; left: 7px;}
    .flip-clock-dot.top { top: 17px; }
    .flip-clock-dot.bottom { bottom: 8px; }

    .flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label { font-size: 11px; }
    .flip-clock-divider.days .flip-clock-label { right: -58px; }
    .flip-clock-divider.hours .flip-clock-label { right: -58px; }
    .flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label { right: -64px; }
    .flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label { right: -64px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li { line-height: 50px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul { width: 37px; }
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn { font-size: 30px; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code and tell if it is ok :

```
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 82px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 110%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #000;
}
.clock {
width: 100%;
height: 116px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 14%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 82px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 110%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #000;
}
.flip-clock-divider {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1%;
  height: 100px; 
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 94%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  color: #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 100%; }
  .flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 14%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 82px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #000;
  line-height: 110px;
}
```

Comment: don't miss to place the file above flipclock.css

Comment: it depends to your layout and the position of your clock division , i maked it according to the website  flipclockjs.com.i can't help you without seeing your page ,you can use jsfiddle

Comment: in the website i used : .header .clock {
width: 100%;
height: 116px;
margin: 0 auto;
} and in the code above i use just the class .clock without parent class

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, we are working to make FlipClock.js inherently responsive and themeable without any hacks. You can checkout the details here. The work is still in progress which you can always check here: https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/issues/161.

Comment: Justin do you have a responsive version for this?

Answer (score 1):

A good solution could be to mix @uzb answer and this. It was posted here as well: [resizing flipclock.js not resizing as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946573/resizing-flipclock-js-not-resizing-as-expected/39124716#39124716)

Use these media queries as suggested by @uzb but adjust only these variables

```
$clock-flip-font-size: 120px
$clock-flip-border-radius: 8px
$clock-digit-gap: 20px
$clock-dot-size: 20px

$clock-height: ($clock-flip-font-size * 1.2)
$clock-flip-width: ($clock-flip-font-size * 0.8)
$clock-flip-margin: ($clock-digit-gap / 2)
$clock-flip-section-width: (2 * ($clock-flip-width + 2 * $clock-flip-margin))

$clock-flip-bg: #607D8B
$clock-flip-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
$clock-flip-font-color: #F44336
$clock-flip-font-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000
```

This is a solution adapted from one of the repo's [closed issue](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/issues/13#issuecomment-140015124) (unsolved). It seems that the dev's promised a new API but that was more than 1 year ago.

It's not perfect as there are some issues when setting `$clock-flip-font-size: 120px`. Also, when minutes are being displayed as 3 digits, the "Minutes" text is not `centered`.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/jimasun/pen/PzAqVw/

```
// 
// ------------------------- FlipClock
// 
$clock-flip-font-size: 120px
$clock-flip-border-radius: 8px
$clock-digit-gap: 20px
$clock-dot-size: 20px

$clock-height: ($clock-flip-font-size * 1.2)
$clock-flip-width: ($clock-flip-font-size * 0.8)
$clock-flip-margin: ($clock-digit-gap / 2)
$clock-flip-section-width: (2 * ($clock-flip-width + 2 * $clock-flip-margin))

$clock-flip-bg: #607D8B
$clock-flip-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
$clock-flip-font-color: #F44336
$clock-flip-font-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000

.countdown-wrapper
  left: 50%
  position: absolute
  top: 50%
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul
  height: $clock-height
  margin: 0 $clock-flip-margin
  width: $clock-flip-width
  box-shadow: $clock-flip-shadow

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li
  line-height: $clock-height

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn
  background-color: $clock-flip-bg
  color: $clock-flip-font-color
  font-size: $clock-flip-font-size
  text-shadow: $clock-flip-font-shadow

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul,
.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn
  border-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down
  border-bottom-left-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius
  border-bottom-right-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after
  top: (($clock-height / 2) - 1px)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot.top
  top: ($clock-height / 2 - $clock-flip-font-size * 0.2 - $clock-dot-size / 2)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot.bottom
  top: ($clock-height / 2 + $clock-flip-font-size * 0.2 - $clock-dot-size / 2)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot
  height: $clock-dot-size
  left: $clock-dot-size
  width: $clock-dot-size
  background: $clock-flip-bg

.countdown .flip-clock-divider
  height: $clock-height
  width: ($clock-dot-size * 3)
  &:first-child
    width: 0

.countdown .flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label,
.countdown .flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label
  right: -1 * $clock-flip-section-width

.countdown .flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label
  color: $clock-flip-font-color
  font-size: $clock-flip-font-size / 4
  width: 2 * $clock-flip-width + 4 * $clock-flip-margin
// 
// ------------------------- FlipClock
//
```