# Center Flipclock and change text to white

Tags: css, flipclock

I have Flipclock working fine on my website, but I need to change the "days:  Hourrs:  Minutes:" text to white, but can't find what css to add/amend

also (I'm using bootstrap3) I can;t get the Flipclock to center in a div. I currently have the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<div class="clock center-block" style="margin:2em;" align="center"></div>
```

But the clock stubbornly stays to the left.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change header text to white (edited):

```
.flip-clock-wrapper .flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Class `.center-block` from Bootstrap applies `margin: 0 auto;` and you're overwriting that with `style="margin:2em;"`. Remove that style and the clock should center appropriately. You may need to set an explicit `width` on the clock. [FlipClock's website](http://flipclockjs.com/) uses a default of `460px`:

```
.flip-clock-wrapper .clock {
    width: 460px;
    height: 116px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle example of your problem?

Comment: It would be better if you could isolate the problem to a Fiddle.

Comment: Well, it looks like the centering worked. I forked the fiddle and made some changes: https://jsfiddle.net/da9ptksw/1/. I also edited my answer slightly above to take into account the `.flip-clock-wrapper` class in place of the `.header` class FlipClock's website was using.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty advanced solution here! It will allow you to change the all colours and shadows in addition to the size.

[resizing flipclock.js not resizing as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946573/resizing-flipclock-js-not-resizing-as-expected/39124716#39124716)